# Как реализовать AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть таблица, в которой есть такого вида записи:

```
    <tr id="6186">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Имя&nbsp;<a href="http://vk.com/id6186" target="_blank">Фамилия</a><br/>Заходил(а): 26.07, в 19:02 MSK</td>
    <td>Город</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club33393308' target='_blank'>ЦП: стартапы и бизнес</a></li>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club17568841' target='_blank'>Телеканал ДОЖДЬ</a></li>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club4537617' target='_blank'>The Village Петербург</a></li>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club28261334' target='_blank'>TJ</a></li>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club24946565' target='_blank'>Илья Варламов</a></li>
<li><a href='http://vk.com/club19720218' target='_blank'>Cossa</a></li>
</ul></td>
<td>
                    <select name="status">
        <option selected value="1">Не обработан</option>
        <option value="2">Отсечка: Не верю м.ж.</option>
        <option value="3">Отсечка: Закрыты ЛС</option>
        <option value="4">В работе</option>
        <option value="5">Отказался</option>
        <option value="6">Нет времени</option>
        <option value="7">Не живёт в ...</option>
        <option value="8">Согласен</option>
        <option value="9">Отправил данные</option>
        <option value="10">[Другое]</option>
       </select><br/>
       <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Комментарии(0)
    </a>
    </td></tr>
```

И есть таблица `users_full`, из которой эти записи (по примеру выше) выводятся.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе какого-то варианта из списка (`select`) данные о том, какой вариант выбран уходили на условный `ajax.php?user=$id&status=$selected_option` (где `$id` в примере, указанном выше = 6186). И чтобы в случае успеха (ajax.php вернул "ОК") чтобы `<tr id="6186">` изменился на `<tr id="6186" class="success">`

Без перезагрузки страницы, AJAX'ом.

Как это реализовать? Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно подойдет такой вариант, в самом упрощенном виде с использование jQuery:

```
var usersFullAjax = (function() {
    var $target,
        $parent_target;

    var _ajax = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax.php?user=' + $parent_target.attr('id') + '&status=' + $target.val(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
             if ( response === 'ok') {
               $parent_target.addClass('success');
             } 

             if ( response === 'error') {

             }

            },
            error: function(res) {

            }
        });
    }


    return {
        'init': function() {
            $(document).on('change', 'select[name="status"]', function() {
                $target = $(this);
                $parent_target = $target.parents('tr');
                _ajax($target);
            });
        }
    }

})();

usersFullAjax.init();
```